# Is there a way to cast in the `Where` part of an Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, casting, entity-framework-6

**To be clear, I am not referring to performing a `.Cast<T>` on the results of an EF call.**

I'm trying to implement a partial search on a number field.

When creating a SQL script, it is easy to convert a column to another data type:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Employees
WHERE CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%95%';
```

Is there any sort of equivalent in a LINQ query?

I can't modify the datatypes on the entity that I'm querying, and `Id` was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158634/doing-a-cast-within-a-linq-query) question can help you

Comment: You might look into the `SqlFunctions` class.  It has a number of methods that are directly supported by the LINQ provider.  I don't know if it has a `Cast` or `Convert` method.  IIRC, it has `StringConvert`

Comment: That SQL query is actually a bug. If you have to convert an Id, which should have no business meaning, into a *string* so you can perform a text search, something is very wrong. At the very least, you'll have to scan the entire table since the cast and wildcard search prevent the use of indexes

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem with X and think Y is the answer. When you run into problems with Y, you ask about Y, not X. In this case, you seem to think that a wildcard search on a *number* could solve your problem. What *is* your actual problem? Why are you looking for 95 in the middle of a random ID?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would classify your comment as an XY distraction. You don't have a direct answer, so you try to deflect away from a problem you can't solve. There are **PLENTY** of times when for some reason a value is stored in a database as a number within a legacy system when no math will be performed on it. There are also plenty of times when a partial match may need to be performed on said properties. As I said in my question, the fact that I used `ID` was for example purposes only.

Comment: @LeeonTM Thanks, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @krillgar actually, no. If that's the case, it means it's a business ID that contains business data. It also means that it can be parsed, and the data extracted, eg in a calculated column. A *persisted* calculated column can be indexed. You could also use Full Text Search on a textual column to speed up searching. So, what is the original problem? Can you use FTS? Or is parsing the ID a better option? How many rows are there?

Comment: @Amy You're right. Want to make that up as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: @krillgar one case I can think where wildcard searching of an ID would make sense is an ERP user that tries to find a record by typing part of an ID, typically a business key. FTS *is* used in such cases to speed up the search. It's also used to search across multiple fields without writing multiple `OR` conditions in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know why ToString doesn't work, but this is what works for me. Without needing SqlFunctions:

```
            context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Id.ToString().Contains("95")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var q = db.Employees
    .Where(emp => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal) emp.Id).Contains("95"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a `SqlFunctions` solution, there's always `ExecuteQuery`

```
var ids = db.ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%{0}%'", "95")
```

(This may not be exactly correct for the parameter.)

Comment: In most cases, I would agree and accept this. However, in my particular case, there is a bunch of other filtering and stuff going on that would make hand rolling a query too problematic. I apologize for not stating that in the question, however I want to keep them focused on the exact problem. This would definitely help others though! Thanks. :D